# Unable to redirect to a naked domain from Heroku using Hostgator

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

I'm trying to use my Hostgator domain with my Heroku app, everything works except the naked domain.
Redirect didn't work for me and they don't provide ALIAS or ANAME?

Any thoughts?

Comment: You might be able to use the `proximo` addon to get a static IP-address, and add a `A` record to it. It is a quite expensive addon though. If you really need to use a "naked" domain, I would consider switching to DNSimple or someone else who can provide `ALIAS/ANAME` records.

Comment: I wrote a solution for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989136/using-pointdns-on-heroku-to-manage-ssl-and-non-www-to-www-redirects/51973660#51973660

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending hours with the customer service I found what I need.
Hostgator does not provide this feature to map to naked domains without A records.

Thankfully I was able to find http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect

It's a free service and does the trick...