# Using PointDNS on Heroku to manage SSL and non-www to www redirects

Tags: ssl, redirect, heroku, https

I've been using Heroku to host and manage a website of mine that requires an SSL certificate.  For the last year and a half I've been using ZerigoDNS to manage my domain and SSL redirecting (although, redirecting from non-https, non-www to https and www does not work).

I just got a notice from Heroku that they will be shutting down ZerigoDNS soon and they recommend switching to PointDNS.  I couldn't find any information in the PointDNS documentation about managing SSL redirects.

Here's what I'm looking to do:

1. non-www non-https redirects to https and www
2. non-https redirects to https and www
3. https but non-www redirects to https and www

The reason everything needs to be forwarded to https and www is that's what the ssl cert was created for (the www is required.  I don't have a wildcard certificate).

Does anyone familiar with PointDNS know how to to set up the records and redirects properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, add both [www.your-domain.com](http://www.your-domain.com) and your-domain.com as custom domains under settings or run below commands

```
heroku domains:add domainname.com
heroku domains:add www.domainname.com
```

For redirection, you need to do it via server, eg. if you are using apache you can achieve redirections via .htacess file.

Also, you can only redirect non-www to www with pointDNS redirect option

Answer (score 0):

Regarding non-www to www redirects, I just got that to work as follows:

First, you *must* add both `www.your-domain.com` and `your-domain.com` as custom domains.

```
heroku domains:add andrewpuglionesi.com
heroku domains:add www.andrewpuglionesi.com
```

I have a CNAME record with name `www.my-domain.com.`. The text in its data field is `my-heroku-domain.herokuapp.com.` I also have an alias record with the name `my-domain.com.`, and I made its data field `www.my-domain.com.` In other words, the alias just points to the CNAME.

I don't know if this is well-advised, but it seems to work (and without sticking `www` in the user's URL, at that). It simply solves the problem where you can't access pages other than the index without having `www` there). I like how Heroku and PointDNS' documentation both say you can easily do redirects and then don't actually explain how to... I guess this is one way.

I've previously been able to force https protocol through the backend of a Django site. I can't remember the exact method I used, but you might be able to do it without the DNS stuff.